# How to position a Chrome Extension (React and TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my chrome extension to appear on the right side of the page, like ZoomInfo extension and SimilarWeb extension.

Currently, the extension appears from the location of the extension button.

I am using React and TypeScript, here is my index.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.createElement("div");
rootElement.id = "react-chrome-app";
document.body.appendChild(rootElement);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Is it possible to change it in the index.css?

Should I use specific styling to the index.html?

Both [Is there a way to change the position/location of a chrome extension popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927030/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-position-location-of-a-chrome-extension-popup) and [Create iframe using Google Chrome Extension manifest v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867944/create-iframe-using-google-chrome-extension-manifest-v3) are not working.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question [Is there a way to change the position/location of a chrome extension popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927030/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-position-location-of-a-chrome-extension-popup) seems to give the answer. - _"it is not possible to reposition the built in popup"_

Comment: The way to effectively change the location of the popup is to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) to inject your custom code into the current page and listen for the event that fires when the extension icon is clicked on